# I received a URL from a server with a unicode é in it (\U00e9). How do I create an NSURL with it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, unicode, nsstring

Whenever I try to create an NSURL from it, I always receive nil back. How do I make it work?

Small example:

```
let str = "https://montr\\U00e9al.ca".stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
NSURL(string: str)
```

Which always gives me nil back. Even if I replace the \u00e9 with é it still returns nil.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in Objective-C or Swift?

Answer (score 0):

You should make unicode in braces and add percent for it like this:

```
let str = "https://www.montr\u{00e9}al.ca".stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Comment: Still results in `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have any control over the server, you should fix the server to provide proper URLs. If you don't have control over it, but can choose a different service, do so. There's no guarantee that improperly encoded URLs will be the only problem coming from that server.

If you can't switch servers, you may need to do something like this:

```
let percentEncodedURLString = NSURL(dataRepresentation: str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, relativeToURL: nil).relativeString
```

This is the Swift version of what [Apple recommends in the Foundation release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/#10_11URL). I strongly recommend that you read that section to understand the issues with other approaches.